# concurrently, how to manage values/states and avoiding a race condition

Tags: go, race-condition

How to properly set/modify a value based on events/conditions that happen after process has started, while dealing with [Goroutines](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/1) without creating a race condition.

For example, the following "works (is buggy)" and output is:

```
ping, foo=true
ping, foo=false
ping, foo=true
ping, foo=true
ping, foo=true
```

<kbd>https://play.golang.org/p/Y3FafF-nBc</kbd>

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type test struct {
    ch  chan string
    foo bool
}

func (t *test) run() {
    for {
        select {
        case v := <-t.ch:
            fmt.Printf("%+v, foo=%+v\n", v, t.foo)
            t.foo = false
        default:
        }
    }
}

func (t *test) Ping() {
    t.ch <- "ping"
}

func New() *test {
    t := &test{
        ch: make(chan string),
    }
    go t.run()
    return t
}

func main() {
    t := New()
    for i := 0; i <= 10; i++ {
        if t.foo {
            t.Ping()
        }
        if i%3 == 0 {
            t.foo = true
        }
    }
}
```

But if compiled or run using the [-race](https://blog.golang.org/race-detector) option, I get this output:

```
$ go run -race main.go
ping, foo=true
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Write at 0x00c4200761b8 by goroutine 6:
  main.(*test).run()
      /main.go:16 +0x1fb

Previous read at 0x00c4200761b8 by main goroutine:
  main.main()
      /main.go:37 +0x5e

Goroutine 6 (running) created at:
  main.New()
      /main.go:30 +0xd0
  main.main()
      /main.go:35 +0x33
==================
ping, foo=false
ping, foo=true
ping, foo=true
ping, foo=true
Found 1 data race(s)
exit status 66
```

Therefore, I would like to know what **concurrency pattern** could I use for being available to change the value of `foo` outside the gorutine and also inside the gorutine without creating a race condition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have some options:

- Using `atomic.Value` : Sample (1)
- Using `sync.RWMutex` : Sample (3)
- Using `sync/atomic` : Sample (6)
- Using only channels and goroutines : Sample (7)

Also see:  [Use a sync.Mutex or a channel?](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/MutexOrChannel)

---

1- You may use `atomic.Value`:

> A Value provides an atomic load and store of a consistently typed
>   value. Values can be created as part of other data structures. The
>   zero value for a Value returns nil from Load. Once Store has been
>   called, a Value must not be copied.
>
> A Value must not be copied after first use.

Like this working sample:

```golang
// to test the panic use go build -race
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync/atomic"
)

type test struct {
    ch chan string
    atomic.Value
}

func (t *test) run() {
    for {
        select {
        case v := <-t.ch:
            fmt.Printf("%+v, foo=%+v\n", v, t.Load())
            t.Store(false)
        default:
        }
    }
}

func (self *test) Ping() {
    self.ch <- "ping"
}

func New() *test {
    t := &test{
        ch: make(chan string),
    }
    t.Store(false)
    go t.run()
    return t
}

func main() {
    t := New()
    for i := 0; i <= 10; i++ {
        if x, _ := t.Load().(bool); x {
            t.Ping()
        }
        //  time.Sleep(time.Second)
        if i%3 == 0 {
            t.Store(true)
        }
    }
}
```

output with `go build -race`:

```
ping, foo=true
ping, foo=false
ping, foo=false
ping, foo=false
ping, foo=false
```

---

2- A little improvment to `func (t *test) run()`:

```golang
func (t *test) run() {
    for v := range t.ch {
        fmt.Printf("%+v, foo=%+v\n", v, t.Load())
        t.Store(false)
    }
}
```

---

3- You may use `sync.RWMutex` and  `sync.WaitGroup`, like this working sample:

```golang
// to test the panic use go build -race
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type test struct {
    ch  chan string
    foo bool
    sync.RWMutex
    sync.WaitGroup
}

func (t *test) run() {
    for v := range t.ch {
        t.Lock()
        r := t.foo
        t.foo = false
        t.Unlock()
        fmt.Printf("%+v, foo=%+v\n", v, r)

    }
    t.Done()
}

func (self *test) Ping() {
    self.ch <- "ping"
}

func New() *test {
    t := &test{ch: make(chan string)}
    t.Add(1)
    go t.run()
    return t
}

func main() {
    t := New()
    for i := 0; i <= 10; i++ {
        t.RLock()
        r := t.foo
        t.RUnlock()
        if r {
            t.Ping()
        }
        //  time.Sleep(time.Second)
        if i%3 == 0 {
            t.Lock()
            t.foo = true
            t.Unlock()
        }
    }
    close(t.ch)
    t.Wait()
}
```

output with `go build -race`:

```
ping, foo=true
ping, foo=true
ping, foo=false
ping, foo=true
ping, foo=false
ping, foo=true
```

---

4- So let's  follow this approach https://talks.golang.org/2013/bestpractices.slide#29:
Original Code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type Server struct{ quit chan bool }

func NewServer() *Server {
    s := &Server{make(chan bool)}
    go s.run()
    return s
}

func (s *Server) run() {
    for {
        select {
        case <-s.quit:
            fmt.Println("finishing task")
            time.Sleep(time.Second)
            fmt.Println("task done")
            s.quit <- true
            return
        case <-time.After(time.Second):
            fmt.Println("running task")
        }
    }
}
func (s *Server) Stop() {
    fmt.Println("server stopping")
    s.quit <- true
    <-s.quit
    fmt.Println("server stopped")
}

func main() {
    s := NewServer()
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    s.Stop()
}
```

---

5- Let's simplify it:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

var quit = make(chan bool)

func main() {
    go run()
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("server stopping")

    quit <- true // signal to quit

    <-quit // wait for quit signal

    fmt.Println("server stopped")
}

func run() {
    for {
        select {
        case <-quit:
            fmt.Println("finishing task")
            time.Sleep(time.Second)
            fmt.Println("task done")
            quit <- true
            return
        case <-time.After(time.Second):
            fmt.Println("running task")
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
running task
running task
server stopping
finishing task
task done
server stopped
```

---

6- Simplified version of your sample:

```golang
// to test the panic use go build -race
package main

import "fmt"
import "sync/atomic"

var ch = make(chan string)
var state int32

func main() {
    go run()
    for i := 0; i <= 10; i++ {
        if atomic.LoadInt32(&state) == 1 {
            ch <- "ping"
        }
        if i%3 == 0 {
            atomic.StoreInt32(&state, 1)
        }
    }
}

func run() {
    for v := range ch {
        fmt.Printf("%+v, state=%+v\n", v, atomic.LoadInt32(&state))
        atomic.StoreInt32(&state, 0)
    }
}
```

output:

```
ping, state=1
ping, state=0
ping, state=1
ping, state=0
ping, state=1
ping, state=0
```

---

7- working sample with channels and without using `Lock()` ([The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/QsyhWpL2Bo)):

```golang
// to test the panic use go build -race
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    go run()
    for i := 0; i <= 10; i++ {
        signal <- struct{}{}
        if <-read {
            ping <- "ping"
        }
        if i%3 == 0 {
            write <- true
        }
    }
}

func run() {
    foo := false
    for {
        select {
        case <-signal:
            fmt.Println("signal", foo)
            read <- foo
        case foo = <-write:
            fmt.Println("write", foo)
        case v := <-ping:
            fmt.Println(v, foo)
            foo = false
        }
    }
}

var (
    ping   = make(chan string)
    signal = make(chan struct{})
    read   = make(chan bool)
    write  = make(chan bool)
)
```

output:

```
signal false
write true
signal true
ping true
signal false
signal false
write true
signal true
ping true
signal false
signal false
write true
signal true
ping true
signal false
signal false
write true
signal true
ping true
```

Comment: Many thanks for the example, wondering if I could use ``atomic.Value`` for saving an instance so that either I could check if is ``nil`` or not and based on that use the methods of it  for example.

Comment: @nbari Yes, You may use it for any  typed value. it internally uses interface{},

Comment: Is there an alternative way  for doing this without using a lock / ``atomic.Value``?

Comment: Many thanks, I am trying to follow this approach https://talks.golang.org/2013/bestpractices.slide#29 but struggling to get it done

Comment: I still wondering/trying to find a way of  how to set/get the value using https://talks.golang.org/2013/bestpractices.slide#29 without using locks, not that I have something agains the locks but is just that I thing this may refer to the so mention share memory by communicating ....

Comment: @nbari  you may send data using channels in this approach, let me add one sample ASAP

Comment: @Amd thanks for the nice examples, but at the end it seems that I am bound to the ``sync`` package, in this case what could be the ``best practice`` to follow, ``sync/atomic``, ``sync/Mutext`` ?

Comment: @nbari see sample code 7, I think you are looking for this., I hope this helps.

Comment: @Amd thanks a lot,  sample 7 use 4 channels and basically is using them like switches, but at the end if I am right this solution is a a full no-blocking versus the ones using the ``sync`` packages right? any limit, concern about having multiple channels ?

Comment: @nbari Also you may use channels in many ways to support concurrency. it depends to use case. at least for this simple case you may think other solutions with channels too.

Answer (score 1):

### Use Mutexes

```
package main

import (
    "sync"
    "time"
    "fmt"
)

var myvar int
var mut sync.Mutex

func main() {
    for {
        go other()
        go printer()
        time.Sleep(time.Duration(1) * time.Second)
    }
}

func other() {
    mut.Lock()
    myvar = myvar +1
    mut.Unlock()
}

func printer() {
    mut.Lock()
    fmt.Println(myvar)
    mut.Unlock()
}
```

### Run (with mutexes)

```
$ go build -race t1.go 
$ ./t1 
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
7
9
10
```

### Run (without mutexes)

```
$ go build t2.go 
$ go build -race t2.go 
$ ./t2 
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Read at 0x000000580ce8 by goroutine 7:
  runtime.convT2E()
      /usr/local/go/src/runtime/iface.go:155 +0x0
  main.printer()
      /.../.../.../GOPATH/t2.go:23 +0x65

Previous write at 0x000000580ce8 by goroutine 6:
  main.other()
      /.../.../.../GOPATH/t2.go:19 +0x3d

Goroutine 7 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      /.../.../.../GOPATH/t2.go:13 +0x5a

Goroutine 6 (finished) created at:
  main.main()
      /.../.../.../GOPATH/t2.go:12 +0x42
==================
1
2
```